# How to get set of operations in dynamic programming

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I would like to ask you how can I get a list of operations I have to do to obtain the result.

The simple example:

There is a number N. Your goal is to find out the minimum operations (x/3, x/2, x-1) you have to do to get 1.

So for example minop(10) = 3 (because **1.** 10-1=9, **2.** 9/3=3, **3.** 3/3=1).

This function is very simple with bottom-up approach in Python:

```
# the opt is an optimum nuber of operations for index to get to one
# the op list should be a list of operations but it does not work
# correctly. For minop(10) would return opt = 3 (three
#operations), op = [1,3,3] (minus one, divide three, divide three)

opt = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] # optimum number of operation for i
op = []

def minop(n):
    opt[1]=0
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        opt[i]=opt[i-1]+1
        op.append(1) # INCORRECT
        if i%2==0:
            opt[i] = min(1+opt[i/2],opt[i])
            op[-1]=2 # INCORRECT
        if i%3==0:
            opt[i] = min(1+opt[i/3],opt[i])
            op[-1]=3 # INCORRECT
    return opt[n],op
```

As you can see, the op list should contain minimum list of operations (represented by numbers) needed to get from `n` to `1` but it contains.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm trying to get a set of operations instead of number of operations.

Comment: Is your question about an algorithm? About your code? What language is this anyway? Read [ask] and clarify yourself.

Comment: It's about algorithm which is represented by Python code.

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: In fact, no it isn't. But I want to learn this kind of stuff to do homework correct :D

Comment: So you have code, and ask for ... the code? I don't get it.

Comment: I have the code, but it is not complete. It returns correct minimum number of operations I have to do to get number 1 from input. But now, I want  to rewrite the code to return a list of this operations. Now, it returns number 3 for input 10, which is correct. 10-1=9, 9/3 = 3, 3/3 = 1 - I used 3 operations. But now, I want function to return a list of this very operations, so the input would be [1,3,3] (or [minus one,divide three, divide three]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most important error in your code is that you update `opt[i]` in both `if` blocks even if the operation does not yield a better result.

Here is a corrected version of your code:

```
def minop(n):
    op = [[], []]
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        ref = i-1
        best = 1
        if i%2==0 and len(op[i/2]) < len(op[ref]):
            ref = i/2
            best = 2
        if i%3==0 and len(op[i/3]) < len(op[ref]):
            ref = i/3
            best = 3
        op.append([best] + op[ref][:]) # slice to get separate copy
    return len(op[n]), op[n]

print minop(10)
```

It outputs:

```
(3, [1, 3, 3])
```

Meaning: 3 operations, which are `-1`, `/3`, `/3`.

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/559066)

Comment: Please note I made a correction to the code just now: `op` should be defined within the function to avoid that a next call will still have the results of the previous call in it.